# Image from ModelForm not being saved

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

I have a Pgae model in wagtail that is holding an ImageField:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from wagtail.users.models import upload_avatar_to
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ProfilePage(Page):
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        # Also updated from user.wagtail_userprofile.avatar
        verbose_name=_("profile picture"),
        upload_to=upload_avatar_to,
        blank=True,
    )
    intro = RichTextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_("Personal introduction"),
        help_text=_("maximum number of characters: 80 characters"),
        max_length=80,
    )
    school = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("School name"), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True
    )
    school_details = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_("School details"),
        help_text=_("example: Faculty of Medicine"),
        max_length=100,
    )
    location = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Location"),
        max_length=50,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("example: Osaka"),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("User")
    )
```

I needed to create a modelform as I am rendering a customized template to set up profile after signing up:

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ProfilePageDetailsForm(ModelForm):
    intro = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Textarea,
        label=_("Personal introduction"),
        help_text=_("maximum number of characters: 80 characters"),
        max_length=80,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ProfilePage
        fields = [
            "avatar",
            "title",
            "school",
            "location",
            "intro",
        ]
```

my view.py:

```py
def profile_details(request: HttpRequest, pk: int = None) -> HttpResponse:
    user = cast("User", request.user)
    profile = ProfilePage.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = ProfilePageDetailsForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfilePageDetailsForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("wagtailadmin_home")

    context = {
        "user": user,
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, "account/profile_details.html", context)
```

my template profile_details.html

```html
<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="{% trans 'submit' %}">
</form>
```

after clicking on submit and filling all the fields including the avatar field I am redirected successfully to the wagtail admin page
but when I check the profile page the avatar image is not existing
I tried to debug but I do not find any error in the process
any help or advice will be very welcome
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `request.FILES` as well as `request.POST` when you re-bind your form in your view - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/